# Why did the same president/prime minster of some country appear so many times at beginning of the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, war-dogs

Why did the same president/prime minster of some country appear so many times at the beginning War Dogs (2016)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Hamid Karzai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamid_Karzai). It's apropos since this movie is about arming Afghanistan's army in the mid 2000s, when he was the president of Afghanistan. I know this is short but TBH I don't know what else to say. ;)